# Summation pattern of alternating signs

Tags: calculus, summation

Trying to put this pattern into sigma notation  -4, 9, -14, .....-44. Cant seem to find a pattern, I see its alternating sign wise, which must have something to do with even and odd powers.

Comment: Did you try the OEIS?

Comment: I've never heard of that, i'll try to google it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy by inspection
$\sum_{n=1}(-1)^n(5n-1)$

Comment: @RoryDaulton:  You raise a good point, but the (unedited) title refers to a "summation pattern" and the body of the Question mentions "sigma notation".  So the Answer provided makes some sense in choosing the series interpretation.

Comment: He said Sigma so I used Sigma. I would have used $S_n=(-1)^n(5n-1)$ since  Sigma denotes a summation. But that's not what the question asked.